# First-person camera script for space game jitters when rotating diagonally

Tags: unity, camera, first-person-shooter

I am working on a first-person shooter that is set in space. Since its set in space, the characters must be able to rotate in 2 directions at once. Currently, I am using 2 transform.rotates which causes my character to jitter whenever you try to move horizontally and vertically.

Edit: my current idea is to combine the two-axis(x and y) into one rotation

```
public float mouseSensitivity = 100f;
public float xRotation = 0f;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    //horizontal
    float mouseX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    this.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up, mouseX);
    print(mouseX);
    //vertical
    float mouseY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity * Time.deltaTime;
    xRotation -= mouseY;
    transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(xRotation, 0f, 0f);
}
```

Thanks

Comment: If you'd like help troubleshooting a problem in your current code, you should include that code in your question. A video or animated gif demonstrating the jitter you're observing would also help.

Comment: [Multiplying a mouse delta by deltaTime is double-dipping your time interval](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/178496/39518). This can add jitter. Have you tried doing this with no extra Time.deltaTime multiplication?

Comment: Also, your last line `transform.localRotation =...` completely overrides the `transform.Rotate` you did earlier around the y axis. Is that deliberate?

Comment: no that's the issue. I'm not sure what I'm should do in order to fix that

Comment: Why not apply transform.Rotate both times, or do both rotations in a single transform.Rotate call?

Comment: ok ill try that.