# How to I make MOUSEY look up

Tags: rotation, movement

I have MOUSEX worked out perfectly, it  moves on the X axis, but when I add the Y axis, I can't use the MOUSEX axis.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

// This script moves the character controller forward
// and sideways based on the arrow keys.
// It also jumps when pressing space.
// Make sure to attach a character controller to the same game object.
// It is recommended that you make only one call to Move or SimpleMove per frame.

public class Move : MonoBehaviour
{
    CharacterController characterController;

    public float speed = 6.0f;
    public float jumpSpeed = 8.0f;
    public float gravity = 20.0f;
    public Transform charBody;
    private Vector3 moveDirection = Vector3.zero;
    public float mouseSense = 11f;
    public float runSpeed = 12f;
    public bool isRunning = false;
    float camRot = 0f;
    public Transform altCamera;

    void Start()
    {
        characterController = GetComponent<CharacterController>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        if (characterController.isGrounded)
        {
            // We are grounded, so recalculate
            // move direction directly from axes

            moveDirection = transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") + transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            moveDirection *= speed;
            moveDirection = transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") + transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
            moveDirection *= speed;





            if (Input.GetButton("Jump"))
            {
                moveDirection.y = jumpSpeed;
            }

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
                moveDirection = transform.forward * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") + transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
                moveDirection *= runSpeed;
                moveDirection = transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") + transform.right * Input.GetAxis("Vertical");
                moveDirection *= runSpeed;

            }
        }
           
        

        // Apply gravity. Gravity is multiplied by deltaTime twice (once here, and once below
        // when the moveDirection is multiplied by deltaTime). This is because gravity should be applied
        // as an acceleration (ms^-2)
        moveDirection.y -= gravity * Time.deltaTime;

        // Move the controller
        characterController.Move(moveDirection * Time.deltaTime);

        float MOUSEY = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSense * Time.deltaTime;
        float MOUSEX = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSense * Time.deltaTime;



        charBody.Rotate(Vector3.up * MOUSEX);

        



        


    }
}
```

Here's my code.

but when i add:

```
camRot -= MOUSEY;
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(camRot, 0f, 0f);
camRot = Mathf.Clamp(camRot, -90f, 90f);
```

The MOUSEX axis doesn't work, and the MOUSEY moves up and down, with the MOUSE axis, but doesn't clamp and the MOUSEX doesn't rotate.

Help please?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(camRot, 0f, 0f);
```

...says "throw out whatever rotation you had before, and replace it with this one that I constructed from one Euler angle"

So any rotation you worked hard to make on the yaw axis is discarded, and you end up with pitch-only rotation, because that's what you've provided on the right hand side of the equation to replace it with.

You might want to make your `camRot` variable a 2-component vector. That way you can store both yaw and pitch and apply them in the same expression.

```
// Put this instead of camRot where you define your member variables.
private Vector2 _cameraAngles;

// ...

// Inside Update, increment your angles:
_cameraAngles.x -= Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * mouseSensitivity;
_cameraAngles.y += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * mouseSensitivity;

// Apply your clamping to the pitch axis:
_cameraAngles.x = Mathf.Clamp(_cameraAngles.x, -90f, 90f);
// Optionally, you might also want to wrap your yaw into a fixed range, like -180 to 180:
_cameraAngles.y = Mathf.DeltaAngle(0f, _cameraAngles.y);

// Apply the rotation all at once:
transform.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(_cameraAngles);
```

Note that [we do not multiply the mouse travel by `Time.deltaTime`](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/178496/39518). These inputs measure how far the mouse has travelled *over the duration* of the previous frame, so they already have a factor of time baked-into them. If we multiply these by `Time.deltaTime`, we "double dip", and can get unwanted inconsistencies in the rate of rotation at different framerates.